# Why do I get inconsistent loss behavior for my deep model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on an image classification results. My training and testing split used the same random_state. Model definition is the same. However, when I run the model for multiple times, three out of four times, the model is not learning, the loss function does not go down; one out of four times, the model is learning, I can get good classificaiton results. I suspect the randomness comes from the ImageDataGenerator(). But I cannot figure out how to let the model learn every time.

I have a relative small labeled dataset, I don't have ways to increase the data size

I tried different optimizers, different batch size. It doesn't help. I found that when I reduce the trainable layers and make the later fully-connected layers smaller (reduce to 256 units), the model start to learn every time. But why big network does not learn well even on the training data set??? My understanding is that the model will overfit, but why in this case, it is not learning at all?

```
IMAGE_WIDTH=128
IMAGE_HEIGHT=128
IMAGE_SIZE=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
IMAGE_CHANNELS=3 # RGB color

os.chdir(r"XXX")
filenames = os.listdir(r"XXX")
ref_db= pd.read_csv(r"XXX")
ref_db['obj_id']= [str(i)+ '.tif' for i in  ref_db.OBJECTID.values  ]
ref_db2= ref_db[['label', 'obj_id' ]]
ref_db2['label'] = ref_db2['label'].apply(str)


train_df, validate_df = train_test_split(ref_db2, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
train_df = train_df.reset_index(drop=True)
validate_df = validate_df.reset_index(drop=True)

total_train = train_df.shape[0]
total_validate = validate_df.shape[0]
batch_size=64   

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=15,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df, 
    r"XXX", 
    x_col='obj_id',
    y_col='Green_Roof',
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode='binary',
    batch_size=batch_size
)                                       


inputs= Input(shape=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 3))
base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,)
for layer in base_model.layers[:-3]:
    layer.trainable = False

x = base_model(inputs)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(x)
#x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)    
model_vgg= Model(inputs=inputs , outputs=predictions)
model_vgg.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#########################
history = model_vgg.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_validate//batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train//batch_size,
    verbose=2
)
```

This is the unwanted behavior, Model is not learning, all observations are predicted as 1, the loss is not dropping

```
Found 756 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Found 190 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/50
 - 4s - loss: 4.0464 - acc: 0.6203 - val_loss: 4.9820 - val_acc: 0.6875
Epoch 2/50
 - 2s - loss: 4.3811 - acc: 0.7252 - val_loss: 4.8856 - val_acc: 0.6935
Epoch 3/50
 - 2s - loss: 5.0209 - acc: 0.6851 - val_loss: 5.3556 - val_acc: 0.6641
Epoch 4/50
 - 2s - loss: 4.3583 - acc: 0.7266 - val_loss: 4.1142 - val_acc: 0.7419
Epoch 5/50
 - 2s - loss: 4.9317 - acc: 0.6907 - val_loss: 4.7329 - val_acc: 0.7031
Epoch 6/50
 - 2s - loss: 4.6275 - acc: 0.7097 - val_loss: 5.3998 - val_acc: 0.6613
Epoch 7/50
```

This is the expected behavior, model is learning, both 1 and 0 are predicted, the loss is dropping

```
Found 756 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Found 190 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/50
 - 4s - loss: 2.1181 - acc: 0.6484 - val_loss: 0.8013 - val_acc: 0.6562
Epoch 2/50
 - 2s - loss: 0.6609 - acc: 0.7096 - val_loss: 0.5670 - val_acc: 0.7581
Epoch 3/50
 - 2s - loss: 0.6539 - acc: 0.6912 - val_loss: 0.5923 - val_acc: 0.6953
Epoch 4/50
 - 2s - loss: 0.5695 - acc: 0.7083 - val_loss: 0.5426 - val_acc: 0.6774
Epoch 5/50
 - 2s - loss: 0.5262 - acc: 0.7176 - val_loss: 0.5386 - val_acc: 0.6875
```

Comment: try scaling input features to [0, 1]. Due to specifics of TF input weights initialization, for values [0, 255] (and such) the initial hyperplane doesn't get any negative/positive results and the resulting gradient is zero.

Comment: I found that when I reduce the trainable layers and make the later fully-connected layers smaller (reduce to 256 units),  the model start to learn every time. But why big network does not learn well even on the training data set??? My understanding is that the model will overfit, but why in this case, it is not learning at all?

Comment: there is no simple answer to this question. It is most likely because gradients are too small, but there are too many reasons why it can be so - from vanishing gradients problem to peculiarities of the data. Did you by chance use sigmoid activation in hidden layers?